# AWS CodeDeploy to version my Javascript files

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, deployment, bitbucket

I would like to configure CodeDeploy to version my .js files. So even if users keep pages open I want the cache to be refreshed after release.

P.S. I am open to other solutions to the matter.

Thanks

Comment: You aren't really looking to doing it using `CodeDeploy`. You can version using `grunt`, which can be called using `CodeDeploy`.

Comment: Do you think you can direct me to a link with instructions on how to do both parts, please.